# how to pass table data with dynamically generated rows in angular js from view to angular controller

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I want to pass data from a table with dynamically generated rows using `ng-    repeat` directive having textboxes, select box to angular controller as a list.

Below is the code i am using. In the Javascipt you can see only one column is dynamically generated but all others are created using input.

```
 <div ng-app="Home" ng-controller="TestController" data-ng-init="init()">
            <table class="users">

                <tr id="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="input in regdata">
                    <td>
                        <Label>{{input.Name}}</Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select ng-options="s.Name for s in typeList" ng-model="SeltypeList" ng-change="getselectval(SeltypeList,$index)"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="Label" />
                    </td>

                    <td ng-if="SeltypeList" ng-hide="SeltypeList.Name=='text'">                        
                        <input type="text" name="value" ng-model="value" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" ng-click="add(SeltypeList,Label,value)" />
                    </td>
                </tr>                
            </table>           
        </div>    

<script>
        var app = angular.module('Home', []);
        app.controller('TestController', function ($scope, $http) {

                $scope.add = function (SeltypeList,Label,Value) {

                $http.post('/Test/Insert', $scope.model).then(function (res) {
                    debugger;

                }); 

            }


        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Dear Gowtham, For more clarity, I suggest to repeat the question sentence from the title at the end of the question-body.

Comment: can  you explain little bit, what do you want exactly?

Comment: Hi,I have created a table with dynamically generated rows using ng-repeat..i have to insert all the data present in rows when clicked on submit button to DB.Here the challenge is pass that data in each of the columns to angular controller.Since there are text boxes in each row which are static and not from list created using ng-repeat.I am unable pass data to angular controller

Comment: Create an array in your controller, the array is populated from your db, push new things into the array which will be repeated in your template with the digest loop. You will also need a method in your controller to post all the data back to some serverside code to update the db

Comment: from where are you retrieving `regdata`if it is not in controller? bind this simply with ng-model

Comment: I really don't get this. According to your html snippet, you have a table with rows, and each row has its data with a submit button. The flow should be that when the submit button for a row is clicked, the data for that row is submitted to the database (or your controller), else, each row will not have a submit button but there will be one submit button for the whole table.. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @DominicOrim There will be only one submit button for the entire table.Here comes the problem.I am generating rows dynamically based on data i get which will have page like Column1  Column2   Column 3.Here lets say Row1 is like                                Name    Combobox   TextBox                                               Row 2                               Title       Combobox   TextBox                                   Here Name,Title.....are coming from DB and based on that only i am generating rows.Now when i click on submit all the row values should pass as list to angular cntrllr

Comment: @PrasannaSasne please find the details in above comment

Comment: you are saying dyanamically you are generating row, but if i look into your code i can see neither `regdata` nor `typeList` is defined inside respective controller.From where are you retrieving thats data?or are you passing data to controller directly from states which is in app.routes.js file? will you please explain how you are populating data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two way data binding, so on click on button you will get selected row data.

```
 <div ng-app="Home" ng-controller="TestController as TCtrl">
        <table class="users">

            <tr id="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="input in regdata track by $index">
                <td>
                    <Label data-ng-model="TCtrl.input.name">{{input.Name}}</Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select 
                        ng-options="s.Name for s in typeList" 
                        ng-model="TCtrl.input.SeltypeList" 
                        ng-change="TCtrl.getselectval(SeltypeList,$index)">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="TCtrl.input.Label" />
                </td>

                <td ng-if="SeltypeList" ng-hide="TCtrl.input.SeltypeList.Name=='text'">                        
                    <input type="text" name="value" ng-model="TCtrl.input.value" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" 
            ng-click="add(SeltypeList,Label,value)" />
                </td>
            </tr>                
        </table>           
    </div>
```

and inside controller you can have code like below,

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('Home', []);
    app.controller('TestController', function ($http) {
            var vm = this;  
            vm.input = {
              name : "",
              SeltypeList : "",
              Label : "",
              value : ""
             }
            vm.add = function (SeltypeList,Label,Value) {

            $http.post('/Test/Insert', vm.input).then(function (res) {
                debugger;

            }); 
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I need to pass all the rows data as list to my controller when clicked on submit button.

Comment: @Gowtham, it's better if you explain from where are you getting regData

Comment: In controller the below code i am writing to get regdata                   
   $scope.init = function () {
                $http.get('/Test/GetJsonResult').then(function (d) {
                    $scope.regdata = d.data;
                    console.log(d.data);
                });
                $scope.IsVisible = true;
            };